# crash when app From background to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios13

crash when applicationWillEnterForeground

tried to use zombie objects,but it not work

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6565656565656569
VM Region Info: 0x6565656565656569 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 7306357445371454826  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   QuartzCore                      0x00000001addf8954 CA::Layer::sublayers+ 1411412 () + 52
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab8eea9c _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 228
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab8eea9c _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 228
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab4ada0c -[UIWindow dealloc] + 144
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a71aa3a4 _object_remove_assocations + 352
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a71a6d20 objc_destructInstance + 100
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a71addb8 _objc_rootDealloc + 48
7   QuartzCore                      0x00000001adde9dc4 -[CALayer dealloc] + 416
8   QuartzCore                      0x00000001add730bc CA::release_objects+ 864444 (X::List<void const*>*) + 32
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001ade00520 CA::Layer::free_transaction+ 1443104 (CA::Transaction*) + 412
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001add73990 CA::Transaction::commit+ 866704 () + 932
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab4a25d4 _afterCACommitHandler + 140
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e9c48 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e4b34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e5100 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e48bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b124f328 GSEventRunModal + 104
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab4796d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
18  FuturesApp                      0x0000000104cde230 main + 6087216 (main.m:14)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a726f460 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a72435f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7242a60 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73ea068 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e5188 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a73e48bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a7724994 -[NSRunLoop+ 31124 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a7724874 -[NSRunLoop+ 30836 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ab51149c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a78550b0 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a71891ec _pthread_start + 124
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a718caec thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7264c8c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a71864e0 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 676
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a72b67a8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 59304 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b60413fc void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 558076 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 108
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b6044dcc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 572876 () + 200
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b6044ab4 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 572084 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b6045dc0 std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 576960 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a71891ec _pthread_start + 124
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a718caec thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7264cdc __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a71871a0 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 92
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7187110 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow$VARIANT$armv81 + 260
3   Foundation                      0x00000001a773cdf4 -[NSRecursiveLock lock] + 24
4   FuturesApp                      0x00000001056dae30 __24-[TKHeartChecker start:]_block_invoke.91 + 36
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7139610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a713a184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7113b7c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 668
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7120110 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 344
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a71208b0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7189f64 _pthread_wqthread + 212
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a718cae0 start_wqthread +
```

8[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFXfC.png)

Comment: Have you written any code in applicationWillEnterForeground? Or in any other function except didFinishLaunching? If Yes, please do mention the code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code in `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
   if (_tradeViewTimer) {
        [_tradeViewTimer invalidate];
        _tradeViewTimer = nil;
    }
} i tried to ignore this code,but always crashed